# new iPad (iPad 3), how to deal with images? JS Script to auto load the correct size?

Tags: javascript, css, ipad

SO now that the new ipad is on the market what's the best practice to deal with the images for your website?

there is there any script that automatically choose the versione x1 or x2 based on screen resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it a few different ways- either in the CSS directly using a different media query, or in Javascript, using the window.devicePixelRatio property.

This post has a good explanation of how to do it:

http://mikepultz.com/2012/03/how-to-make-images-look-good-on-the-ipad-3/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a media query. It's the most simple way. Here's the code I'm using:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
   .your-class-name {
      background: url("images/your-image@2x.png"); 
      background-size: 18px 18px; 
   }
}
```

Remember:

• Add the '@2x' before your extension

• Use the same 'background-size' as your non-retina images

• Retina images are twice the size as non-retina

Exp:

non-Retina = 100px x 100px

Retina = 200px x 200px

Comment: The @2x in the file name isn't necessary for web sites. Also, minor nitpick: the retina images are 4 times the size (100x100=10000/200x200=40000)

Comment: You're right, the @2x isn't necessary if for website. Technically, isn't for iOS anymore either.

Answer (score 1):

Was just looking into this myself a few days ago - you might be interested in an adaptive route. Check this out http://adaptive-images.com/ pretty straightforward to implement. It shows you how to change it based on the display - be aware that means you'll have to save out higher res images and these devices might not have the best internet connection.

Comment: actually this doesnt sound as smart as I thought. I'll keep searching

Comment: Sorry, can't really have a bigger image, without having a bigger image. :(